# When a word is both a な and の adjective?

Tags: meaning, particle-の, na-adjectives

I've recently encountered words like 「いろいろ」which apparently counts as both a な and a の adjective.

Just curious if there's some difference in meaning when one is used instead of the other.

Comment: Related: [Can I always use 色々な or do I have to use 色々の sometimes?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3677/542), and [why is it that some 形容動詞 accepts の after it while some only accepts な after it?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/920/542)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dictionary 色々(いろいろ) can be used as a noun (名詞), as a na-adjective (形容動詞), and even as an adverb (副詞).
But the meaning is basically the same.

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/15710/meaning/m0u/%E8%89%B2%E8%89%B2/