# What are the different uses of iroiro?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

I already know there is the adjective iroiro+na, and I've learned that, but recently I've learned that iroiro+to and iroiro+no are different ways to use "iroiro", which I have not learned in class, yet I've already finished the course... I can't really find an answer online though. Any explanation will help.

Thank you.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14640/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3677/9831

Comment: 「いろいろ」の使い方がいろいろある！

Answer (score 1):

The footnoted answer to your question leads to a distinction between the adjectival “-na” and adverbial “-to” suffixes.

I stumbled into an expression which seems to be a hybrid.  In the Netflix version of 僕だけがいない街, Episode #1, Satoru’s mother tells him she’s there to help him after he was injured in a traffic accident.  She points out, 「いろいろと不便だべさ」.

This puzzled me “bigly“.  Having said that, I think there’s a clue in this use of “big” as an adverb.  As in, “It’s variously inconvenient.”

BTW, the title of the show on Netflix is “Erased”.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this hahaha. Btw i

Comment: -Just pressed post by accident. I saw that show. Liked it. Hated the ending.

Comment: Thanks!  I use Netflix USA shows to study Japanese.  Takes me forever to retype the Japanese captions into a study sheet.  I line them up next to the easily downloadable English subtitles and marvel at how misleading they are!  Great education.  Before I am accused of thread drift, I’ll look for a thread where we can discuss the joys of using Netflix USA for study.  Will continue discussion there.